# VSTS test case parameters are not editable

Tags: azure-devops

I have an issue with manual tests in `VSTS` since yesterday.

When I try to add a parameter to a test step, the field in which I should enter the possible values is disabled. I tried with various parameter names, I checked it with different accounts, or using different browsers (Firefox, Chrome and Edge). It's always the same result.

It occurs for existing or news test cases parameters are simply not editable.

[image: vsts screenshot]

When I move the mouse over the text field, The cursor changes from default to cursor, but I can't enter any text.

Anyone has an idea what could I do to make it work?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT screenshot added

Comment: Can you enter any value in it? Your screenshot is the same as mine, but I can set the values.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT no, I can't. The cursor changes from `default` to `cursor`, but I can't enter any text into that field

Comment: Which browser are you using? Does it work if clearing the browser cache?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I tried Firefox, Chrome and Edge. Same issue occurs for colleagues too.

Comment: @Szeki This issue has been fixed. (I updated my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue too (different account with different machine). I submit a [feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3104880), you can vote it.

The workaround is that you can create/modify test case and set parameters' value through [Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286659(v=vs.120).aspx).

You also can modify test case in visual studio and set parameters' value.

Update:

This issue has been fixed now.

Comment: Yes, confirmed.

Comment: @Szeki Since your issue has been solved, you can mark it as answer.